# Resetting SMC on a Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management, logicboard

About a couple of weeks ago, I tried turning on my Macbook Pro and it seemed completely dead. I plugged in the power cable but it still didn't work. Since it's not under warranty anymore, I opened up the back, disconnected the battery, plugged the power cable in and this time it worked. After booting it up I plugged in the battery and it started charging, I can use my Macbook without the cable fine, but other issues occured.

Battery status:

[image]

Here are my MB specs:

[image]

- I can't power on with the power button so I have to either connect the power cable or
  sometimes disconnect the battery (I think this is based on how
  much the battery is charged)
- Camera doesn't work anymore (no device
  connected)
- Power button doesn't work at all

I can't reset SMC (I can't boot properly and nothing happens after pressing the keys). I've tried all the things listed under this [Apple's Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

I've tried updating the SMC firmware, but it didn't help.

Isn't it possible to reset the SMC (which I think is the cause of this) through the terminal or by disconnecting the internal battery(logics board?) or something similar?

Comment: nope, not by Terminal. Reduce your brightness to minimum then reset SMC, if it worked you will know. Also tell us the status of your battery.

Comment: Dimming the brightness didn't work. I've added the power status to my question.

Comment: Thanks, so the battery is reporting cycles count of 1132 which is higher than specified by apple, but it reports condition as normal ? (it should say replace battery!), this could be caused by not functioning SMC, so lets find a way to properly reset it for your model.

Comment: Yeah, i've run the hardware diagnostics and it didn't find any problems with the hardware. So maybe I do need to replace the battery but it doesn't explain the other issues. What are other ways to reset the SMC?

Comment: It would explain your power button not working https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Some ppl make the mistake using the cmd instead of the ctrl. On left side of the keyboard press shift+ctrl+alt+power

Comment: I tried both multiple times, didn't work :(